# Solve $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\cos(x+y)+\sin(x+y)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

> Solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos(x+y)+\sin(x+y)$

**My Attempt**
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{2}\cos(x+y-\tfrac{\pi}{4})
$$
Set $t=x+y-\tfrac{\pi}{4}\implies y=t-x+\tfrac{\pi}{4}$
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dt}{dx}-1=\sqrt{2}\cos t\\
\frac{dt}{dx}=\sqrt{2}\cos(t)+1\\
\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{2}\cos(t)+1}=\int dx
$$
How do I proceed further to find the general solution ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\int dx=\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{2}\cos(t)+1}\\
x&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{dt}{\cos t+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{dt}{\cos t+\cos\frac{\pi}{4}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{dt}{2\cos\big(\frac{t}{2}+\frac{\pi}{8}\big)\cos\big(\frac{t}{2}-\frac{\pi}{8}\big)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{\sin\Big[\big(\frac{t}{2}+\frac{\pi}{8}\big)-\big(\frac{t}{2}-\frac{\pi}{8}\big)\Big]}{\cos\big(\frac{t}{2}+\frac{\pi}{8}\big)\cos\big(\frac{t}{2}-\frac{\pi}{8}\big)}dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[\int\tan\Big(\frac{t}{2}+\frac{\pi}{8}\Big)dt-\int\tan\Big(\frac{t}{2}-\frac{\pi}{8}\Big)dt\bigg]\\
&\text{Set }u=\frac{t}{2}+\frac{\pi}{8}\implies dt=2du \quad\&\quad v=\frac{t}{2}-\frac{\pi}{8}\implies dt=2dv\\
x&=\int\tan u.du-\int\tan v.dv=\log|\sec u|-\log|\sec v|=\log|\frac{\sec u}{\sec v}|+C\\
&=\log|\frac{\cos v}{\cos u}|+C=\log\bigg|\frac{\cos\big(\tfrac{t}{2}-\tfrac{\pi}{8}\big)}{\cos\big(\tfrac{t}{2}+\tfrac{\pi}{8}\big)}\bigg|+C\\
&=\log\bigg|\frac{\cos\big(\tfrac{x+y}{2}-\tfrac{\pi}{8}-\tfrac{\pi}{8}\big)}{\cos\big(\tfrac{x+y}{2}-\tfrac{\pi}{8}+\tfrac{\pi}{8}\big)}\bigg|+C=\log\bigg|\frac{\cos\big(\tfrac{x+y}{2}-\tfrac{\pi}{4}\big)}{\cos\big(\tfrac{x+y}{2}\big)}\bigg|+C\\
&=\log\bigg|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan\big(\tfrac{x+y}{2}\big)\bigg|+C\\
&\color{red}{x=\log\bigg|1+\tan\big(\tfrac{x+y}{2}\big)\bigg|+K}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Making $x+y = u\to \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{du}{dx}-1$

$$
\frac{du}{dx} = \sin u+ \cos u +1
$$

this is a separable DE

$$
\frac{du}{\sin u+\cos u + 1} = dx
$$

etc.

NOTE

$$
\sin u+\cos u = \sqrt 2\sin(u+\frac{\pi}{4})
$$

now using the identities

$$
\cos u=2\cos^2(\frac u2)-1\\
\sin u =2\cos(\frac u2)\sin(\frac u2)
$$

we have

$$
\frac{1}{\cos u+\sin u+1} = \frac{1}{2\cos(\frac u2)(\cos(\frac u2)+\sin(\frac u2))} = \frac 12\left(\frac{\sin(\frac u2)}{\cos(\frac u2)}+\frac{-\sin(\frac u2)+\cos(\frac u2)}{\cos(\frac u2)+\sin(\frac u2)}\right)
$$

etc.

Comment: how can it be different from my attempt ?

Comment: Follows a hint to solve the integration part.